# NHibernate Event Upon Insert of Entity into Dictionary- Reference to Parent Object

Tags: nhibernate

I have an entity (the "parent") which contains a dictionary with unidirection one-to-many references to instances of a "child" entities. The HBM file for the parent contains the following attributes for the map tag: `cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="false"`.

An instance of the parent is persisted to the database, then retrieved and a new child instance added to the parent instance dictionary. When the transaction for this update is committed I've noticed that the OnPreInsert method is fired on a registered instance of `IPreInsertEventListener`, with the child instance being inside the Entity property of the `PreInsertEvent` instance passed in.

Is there any way I can find a reference to the parent class in the listener when this dictionary insert is committed? I've tried to register a `IPreCollectionUpdateEventListener` and this doesn't pick anything up.

As I've said, this is a unidirectionary relationship, and I know that I could achieve what I want by making it bidirectional, but this is something that I'd rather not do.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to register a `IPreUpdateEventListener` instance as well.

In this case, you could trap the `parent` object instead and iterate its children to do your stuff.

Comment: I just tried this and the OnPreUpdate method isn't fired, which is rather strange.